# Phabricator installation - change database name prefix

Tags: installation, php, database, shared-hosting

I'm on a shared host and I'm in the process of installing [Phabricator](http://www.phabricator.com). One issue I've come across is created the databases for Phabricator, which want the following,

```
phabricator_audit
phabricator_calendar
phabricator_chatlog
phabricator_conduit
phabricator_countdown
phabricator_daemon
phabricator_differential
phabricator_draft
phabricator_drydock
phabricator_feed
phabricator_file
phabricator_flag
phabricator_harbormaster
phabricator_herald
phabricator_maniphest
phabricator_meta_data
phabricator_metamta
phabricator_oauth_server
phabricator_owners
phabricator_pastebin
phabricator_phame
phabricator_phriction
phabricator_project
phabricator_repository
phabricator_search
phabricator_slowvote
phabricator_user
phabricator_worker
phabricator_xhpast
phabricator_cache
phabricator_fact
phabricator_ponder
phabricator_xhprof
phabricator_pholio
phabricator_conpherence
phabricator_config
phabricator_token
phabricator_releeph
phabricator_phlux
phabricator_phortune
phabricator_phrequent
phabricator_diviner
phabricator_auth
phabricator_doorkeeper
phabricator_legalpad
phabricator_policy
phabricator_nuance
phabricator_passphrase
phabricator_phragment
phabricator_dashboard
phabricator_system
phabricator_fund
phabricator_almanac
phabricator_multimeter
phabricator_spaces
phabricator_phurl
phabricator_badges
```

The issue I am having is that each of these databases begin with the prefix `phabricator_` and because I'm on a shared host, each of my databases begins with the prefix `nkdcsck_`. How do I make Phabricator use the prefix `nkdcsck_` instead of `phabricator_` for its databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this command followed by the name prefix was able to do it,

`bin/config set storage.default-namespace`

So for me I used,

`bin/config set storage.default-namespace nkdcsck`